# Single producer, multiple consumer architecture

Tags: c++, multithreading, lock-free

I am faced with parallelizing a simple poll-process loop that looks like this:

```
while(!done)
    buffer = poll(...)
    foreach(item i in buffer)
        process(i)
```

the problem follows a single producer/multiple consumers pattern except the items produced have to be consumed by ***all*** consumers.

Considering the implementation will have to be multi-threaded C++ code, what kind of data structures should I be using?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: you have this tagged as lock-free.  Are you looking for a lock-free solution (do you know what lock-free solutions are)?

Comment: yes, if possible. Having multiple consumers that all consume everything produced has got me stumped. Naturally, I would like to avoid having to copy the buffers to the consumers.

Comment: the scenario is performance critical, and since the buffers are readonly, i felt that this might be a good application of a lockfree approach. I might be wrong tho.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess the problem would be deciding which consumer to queue a buffer to next, given a choice of consumers that have not yet conusmed the buffer.  It wold not be optimal to queue a buffer, (pointer), to a consumer that was already busy if there is another consumer  for that buffer that is free.  Hmm..

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of consumers in advance, you can have a queue per consumer.

If consumers are added and removed dynamically, you have to decide what to do with messages generated before a consumer was created. If all consumers must handle all messages - use a vector to keep all messages, and have each consumer keep just an index for the last processed message in the server.

Don't forget to synchronize your access to the vector, since it can be reallocated when the producer adds an item

Answer (score 0):

Si I guess the best option is to create a message queue for each consumer.

This means all the consumers have to register with the producer, and then, the producer should queue the message to each message queue.

A good implementation option should be to create a proxy object between the producer and the consumer, the proxy object is an hybrid object, which means it consumes all the messages from the producer but also forwards them to all of the registered consumers.

Comment: I guess that could work,  The buffers may require a pointer/reference count or shared_ptr access to control their lifetime.

Comment: @MartinJames +1 to your comment